# Automotive Relay

Tags: relay, wiring, automotive

In this diagram it shows the power going to a relay (229) I was wondering if anyone could explain to me in simple English (I don't know much about electrics) what the symbols mean to left of J314 going to 86 on the relay. thanks[image]

Comment: How is a question on electronic symbols off topic? People need to stop abusing the close feature.

Answer (score 4):

It indicates a revision in the wiring. For Saab, the brackets refer to options, in which wiring changes depending on features, or in this specific case, the SOP and 2 in triangle mean Start of Production and Revision 2. So some time in the middle of the production for that year or generation changed.

The specific change seems to be that they went from a wimpy 0.5 mm cross section wire to a beefy 4.0 mm cross section wire. The wire order code, color code, location and connections are still the same. Just a better wire. Either to simplify the number of wire sizes used, or because it was needed. Going from 22 to 12 awg seems costly in scale so they must have had a good reason (burnt out wires or failing to trigger the relay)

Answer (score 3):

Triangle may be a note for selective options of coil wire gauge https://www.auto-facts.org/automotive-wiring-diagrams/